# In Python, how do I rotate a matrix 90 degrees counterclockwise?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
>>> def rotate_matrix( k: List[List[int]]):
    """
    For example, if I have:
    m = [[1,2,3],
         [2,3,3],
         [5,4,3]]
    rotate_matrix(m) should give me [[3,3,3],[2,3,4],[1,2,5]]. 
    """
```

Edit: Preferably without numpy.

Comment: I've tried the code in python IDLE and for some reason, it's outputting the original matrix instead of rotating it. Can you please help?

Comment: I just copied the code from the answer and ran it, it is perfect. Please check that you are printing the right array in your code, c.f. print( new_matrix )

Answer (score 13):

Here is the counter clockwise matrix rotation as one line in pure python (i.e., without numpy):

```
new_matrix = [[m[j][i] for j in range(len(m))] for i in range(len(m[0])-1,-1,-1)]
```

If you want to do this in a function, then

```
def rotate_matrix( m ):
    return [[m[j][i] for j in range(len(m))] for i in range(len(m[0])-1,-1,-1)]
```

and either way, the result for

```
m = [ [1,2,3], [2,3,3], [5,4,3]]
```

is

```
[[3, 3, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 5]]
```

Aside, if you want the usual transpose, then the simple one line pure python version is

```
[[m[j][i] for j in range(len(m))] for i in range(len(m[0]))]
```

Comment: I've tried the code in python IDLE and for some reason, it's outputting the original matrix instead of rotating it. Can you please help?

Comment: I just copied the code from here and ran it,  it is perfect.  Please check that you are printing the right array in your code,  c.f.  print( new_matrix )

Comment: this code is good, can you expand this one line of code for understanding? thank you.

Comment: @VrushalRaut   Good question,  perhaps drawing a picture (or two) would help. Will try to find some time to look into it.

Comment: @DrM How would you change the code to rotate the matrix clockwise?

Answer (score 10):

You could use the numpy function rot90

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([[1,2,3],
         [2,3,3],
         [5,4,3]])

def rotate_matrix(mat):
    return np.rot90(mat)
```

Comment: "Edit: Preferably without numpy."

Answer (score 8):

**#solution1**

```
print(list(list(x) for x in zip(*m))[::-1])
```

**#solution2**

```
print([[x[i] for x in m] for i in range(len(m))][::-1])
```

**#solution3**

```
r = []
i = 0
for row in m:
  listToAdd = [item[i] for item in m]
  r.append(listToAdd)
  i +=1
print(r[::-1])
```

Comment: Shorter if you're OK with tuples instead of lists: `list(zip(*m))[::-1]` or `[*zip(*m)][::-1]`

Comment: Why unpacking the m with `*` and then packing it back with `zip`?

Comment: @radoslav006 That's basically the rotation/pivot operation. The arguments to `zip` are distinct lists, and the output of `zip` is the nth element of each list grouped together.

Answer (score 3):

```
def rotate_90_degree_anticlckwise(matrix):
    new_matrix = []
    for i in range(len(matrix[0]), 0, -1):
        new_matrix.append(list(map(lambda x: x[i-1], matrix)))

    return new_matrix


def rotate_90_degree_clckwise(matrix):
    new_matrix = []
    for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
        li = list(map(lambda x: x[i], matrix))
        li.reverse()
        new_matrix.append(li)

    return new_matrix

def rotate_90_degree_clckwise_by_zip_method(matrix):
    return list(list(x)[::-1] for x in zip(*matrix))
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code. This is the way to rotate any matrix by 90 degrees using scratch

[This is the code to have a matrix rotated by 90 degrees][1]

```
    n = input("enter input:")
    l =[]

    while (n !=""):
    
        l.append(n.split(" "))
        n = input("enter input:")
        l1=[]
    for i in range(len(l[0])):
        l1.append([])
    for j in range (len(l1)):
        for p in range(len(l)):
           l1[j].append(l[p][-(j+1)])

    for s in l1:
         print(*s)
'''


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8jHC.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Just flip the matrix vertically, then switch the upper-right triangle with the lower-left triangle

```
def rotate_matrix_ccw(mat):
    if mat is None:
        return None
    n = len(mat)
    if n == 1:
        return mat
    for i in range(n):
        if len(mat[i]) != n:
            raise Exception("Matrix must be square")
    # flip the matrix vertically
    for j in range(n // 2):
        for i in range(n):
            mat[i][j], mat[i][n - 1 - j] = mat[i][n - 1 - j], mat[i][j]
    # switch the upper-right triangle with the lower-left triangle
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            mat[i][j], mat[j][i] = mat[j][i], mat[i][j]
    return mat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the original matrix and create a new one. This is my approach for counterclockwise, for the other way it would be similar.
This doesn't require it to be a square.

```py
def left_rotate(mat):
    if not mat: return []
    colcount = len(mat[0])

    # Initialize empty lists
    new = [list() for _ in range(colcount)]
    # Go through the rows, append elements one by one
    for row in mat:
        for j in range(colcount):
            new[j].append(row[colcount - 1 - j])
    return new
```

Example:

```py
>>> print(left_rotate([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]))
[[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

flip vertically (left to right) then transpose:

```
m = [[1,2,3],
     [2,3,3],
     [5,4,3]]
print([list(x) for x in zip(*[x[::-1] for x in m])])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def rotateMatrix(self, matrix):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(i):
            matrix[i][j], matrix[j][i] = matrix[j][i], matrix[i][j]

    matrix.reverse()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Rotate matrix anti-clockwise 90deg (In-place)

```
def rotate(matrix):
    for i in range(len(matrix) - 1, -1, -1):
        for j in range(i):
            matrix[i][j], matrix[j][i] = matrix[j][i], matrix[i][j]
    matrix.reverse()
```

Rotate matrix clockwise 90deg (In-place)

```
def rotate(matrix):
    matrix.reverse()
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(i):
            matrix[i][j], matrix[j][i] = matrix[j][i], matrix[i][j]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're working with square matrixes (rows == cols) then you can use this:

```py
list(zip(*reversed(a))) # 90 degrees clockwise
```

```py
list(zip(*reversed(a)))[::-1] # 90 degrees counter-clockwise
```

Comment: Small typo in the counter-clockwise code snippet. You must remove the `reversed` so you have: `list(zip(*a))[::-1] # 90 degrees counter-clockwise`

Answer (score 0):

```
def rotated_array(array):
    new_array = np.zeros([array.shape[0], array.shape[1]])
    for i in range(array.shape[0]):
        for j in range(array.shape[1]):
            t = array.shape[0]-j-1          # To Start with last row and first column
            new_array[i, j] = array[t, i]
    return new_array
```

Comment: The shape of new_array is the same as the shape of the original input array. This can’t be correct if new_array is the original input array rotated by 90 degrees.