# Reading in a CSV file with whitespace as value holder as well as delimiter Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, whitespace

Im currently working on the advent of code day 5 task, but im struggling to import the CSV file. Values seem to be separated by whitespace as delimiter, however, there are also whitespaces which are meant to be place holders for a missing value (outline below makes it more clear).

Note: I tried doing this using read_csv from the pandas package

```
    [H]         [H]         [V]    
    [V]         [V] [J]     [F] [F]
    [S] [L]     [M] [B]     [L] [J]
    [C] [N] [B] [W] [D]     [D] [M]
[G] [L] [M] [S] [S] [C]     [T] [V]
[P] [B] [B] [P] [Q] [S] [L] [H] [B]
[N] [J] [D] [V] [C] [Q] [Q] [M] [P]
[R] [T] [T] [R] [G] [W] [F] [W] [L]
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

Is there a way to import CSV files dictating that, when multiple whitespaces occur, they should be treated as a missing value instead and not as a delimiter? Im assuming that I have to manually loop through the file in order to do this.

Comment: if this is your real data, you could look into fixed width file, I believe, the method is: pandas.read_fwf()

Answer (score 0):

Treating it as a CSV and using an off-the-shelf tool is a good idea, but it's a bit of a stretch of the format here. I'd write a custom parser that [pivots the input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250821/in-python-how-do-i-rotate-a-matrix-90-degrees-counterclockwise#comment126614081_68188419), then loops along each line to parse the stack data, filtering out non-data lines along the way:

```py
import re


with open("data.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# isolate the stacks part of the puzzle
stacks_area = []

for x in lines:
    if re.fullmatch(r"\s*", x):
        break

    stacks_area.append(x)

stacks = []

# pivot the raw lines
for x in zip(*lines):

    # discard extra data
    if any(c.isalpha() for c in x):
        # remove non-alpha characters and reverse each stack
        stacks.append([c for c in reversed(x) if c.isalpha()])

for x in stacks:
    print(x)

# TODO: parse and apply the movement instructions from `lines`
```

Output:

```py
['R', 'N', 'P', 'G']
['T', 'J', 'B', 'L', 'C', 'S', 'V', 'H']
['T', 'D', 'B', 'M', 'N', 'L']
['R', 'V', 'P', 'S', 'B']
['G', 'C', 'Q', 'S', 'W', 'M', 'V', 'H']
['W', 'Q', 'S', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'J']
['F', 'Q', 'L']
['W', 'M', 'H', 'T', 'D', 'L', 'F', 'V']
['L', 'P', 'B', 'V', 'M', 'J', 'F']
```

You'll need to use a custom parser anyway for the bottom section (`move 2 from 2 to 1`, etc), although parsing that is pretty straightforward.

Keep in mind these stacks are 0-indexed in Python, and 1-indexed in the custom format.

AOC is intended to be language-agnostic, so basically all problems can be solved without libraries or special formats. That's not to say you can't take advantage of language features from time to time, but don't expect to see standard "business" formatting on the inputs.