# Fixing my code to also working on the test case when the matrix in not square?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, data-structures, linear-algebra

I have this problem to slove...

> Implement the function by allocating a new n X n 2D array.
> Then write the rotation to it by writing the rows of the original matrix to
> the columns in the solution matrix such that they fit the solution requirement. Then copy the new matrix exactly the same to the original matrix
> so that you know for sure you have updated the original matrix to look
> modified.

I wrote the code in Python and it works for empty and square matrixes, but not non-square matrixes. I understand the logic of the problem but do not know the Python syntax to solve it.

Here is my code...

```
rows, cols = (5, 5)
arr1 = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
arr2 = [[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9]]

def showMatrix(arr1):
  if(len(arr1) <= 0 or len(arr1[0]) <= 0):
    print([])
  L = len(arr1[0])
  for i in range(L):
      print(arr1[i])
showMatrix(arr2)
L = len(arr2[0])

for i in range(len(arr2)):
    for j in range(len(arr2[i])):
        arr1[i][len(arr2[i])-j-1] = arr2[j][i]
print()
showMatrix(arr1)
```

I need to rotate any array 90 degrees clockwise.

Comment: What is "the function" that you're supposed to implement?

Comment: Since it says that you should allocate an nXn array, it seems like it's only intended for square matrixes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250821/in-python-how-do-i-rotate-a-matrix-90-degrees-counterclockwise